# Chrome extension call extension script localstorage from content script with nested async function, undefined var returned

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My content script is call to background script through chrome api message pass, here is my **content script** :

```
function getstorage() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:'getlocalstorage',data:"datatopull"}, function(response){
        alert('response : ' + response.data);
    });
}
```

and my **background script** :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
 . . . . .
    }else(message.action=='getlocalstorage'){
        chrome.storage.local.get(message.data,function(item){
            return sendResponse({data:item[message.data]});
        });
    }
})
```

but i know the return(**response.data**) still not contain value because calling async function, how to deal with it ?

Comment: You need to add `return true` before exiting onMessage listener to keep the channel open.

Comment: you are awesome :) thx man

Comment: Fun fact: you don't need to use Messaging here at all. `chrome.storage` is directly accessible from a content script, one of the few APIs that are available there.